# Batch file that detects when its being copied?

Tags: security, batch-file, copy, delete-file

Please can someone help me create a batch file that detects when its being copied.
I am pretty good with batch but all I want to do is put a security warning on my batch program like this: "Do Not Copy This File Or It Will Be Deleted!" then it deletes itself when the user try's to copy it (so it can't be stolen etc...)

Comment: What's to stop someone simply editing your control out of the batch file? This isn't a viable idea.

Comment: @MikeW: yes, it would make more sense by converting it with a batch to exe converter

Answer (score 0):

A running program can lock the file so that nothing else can open it.  I'm not sure how to do this in a batch script, but I assume that there's some way that it could lock itself.  But if the file is just sitting there and no other running process has it locked, that won't work.

Why can't you use file permissions to prevent others from accessing the file?

Answer (score 0):

Not that this will prevent anyone of reading the file and copy it nevertheless...

```
if not "%computername%#%~df0"=="AKOYA#C:\Users\Stephan\test\4\s.bat" echo this has been copied!! & del %~df0
```

Comment: **Ok thank you everyone. I think I will try @Stephans idea then maybe just try change the permission on the file. I was actually looking for code that deletes the file once its being copied instead of copying. Thank you anyway.**